# Пробелма с выбором конкретного делегата в QML Calendar

Tags: qt, qml, calendar

Занимаюсь сейчас с `Calendar` в *QML*, при его описании имеется некое поле `dayDelegate`, в котором описывается то, что будет у нас выступать в качестве квадратика с датой.

В моем случае, я хочу чтобы при нажатии на такой вот день квадратик становился синим и при закрытии сохранял свой цвет, но когда я это делаю синими становятся все квадраты.

Как исправить чтобы квадратик с датой и менял только свой цвет, а не всех?

Comment: Прошу дополнить свой вопрос кодом, иначе никто не поймет где ваша ошибка...

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, вам нужно разобраться с паттерном MVD, и его реализацией в QML, для этого рекомендую почитать вот эту [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/181712/). Реализация цветовой отметки принципиально ничем не отличается от того же списка.

Во-вторых, на сегодня компонент Calendar уже теряет актуальность, поскольку относится к Qt Quick Controls первой версии, а недавно вышла вторая, которая предлагает, например, автоматическое масштабирование на экранах с высокой плотностью пикселов. Так вот, там уже используется компонент MonthGrid.

В третьих, если вам всё-таки нужен Calendar, то при задании стиля делегата поможет таблица со вспомогательными переменными из документации по свойству dayDelegate, которые позволяют регулировать цвет в зависимости от выполнения условий.